# Why not work and no any response?

Tags: php

Why is the below code not working and no response is received? Please help!

I want to check the Name.

```
 <?php
  echo '<form name="form">';
  echo '<input type="text" name="Name" >';
  echo '<input type="button" class="save" value="save" onClick="Check()" />';
  echo '</form>';

$_POST["Name"] = $Name;

echo '<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">';
echo 'function Check(){';
echo 'if( strlen($Name) < 8) {';
echo 'alert("error name");';
echo '}else {';
echo 'form.submit();';
echo '}';
echo '}';
echo '</SCRIPT>';
?>
```

Comment: php is server side language. never use php to add client side code.

Comment: TarangP 22  , thank you! So how can I do this one??

Answer (score 1):

*If you want to do it with pure php*

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['name']) && strlen($_POST['name']) < 8) {
        echo  htmlentities($_POST['name']);
        exit;
    }else {
        //FORM SUBMITION CODE
    }
}
?>
```

For More Look At PHP [**Form Handling**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)